# Regex to match hard pattern

Tags: java, regex

I have this input string:

```
'10,00', '20,00','','aaa','       false   true         '
'aaaaa'','-*/++;;','',-
'1898302',21/07/2011,'12:59',7104, 13:29
```

And I need to match these strings:

```
"10,00" 
"20,00"
""
"aaa"
"       false   true         "
"aaaaa'"
"-*/++;;"
"1898302"
"21/07/2011"
"12:59"
"7104"
"13:29"
```

The regex I'm using in Java at the moment is this: `('[^']*'|[^\s|,]+)`.
[Which doesn't match accurately](https://regex101.com/r/ktQvNc/2); it matches a comma that I don't want.

Can please someone help me to make it more accurate?

Comment: The comma is between single quotation marks, so that match is expected

Comment: One of the single quotation marks actually belongs to the previous word

Comment: Then how do you want to tell one from another?

Comment: Once you know your requirements, do not forget to update the question.

Comment: @LeonardoChirivì Perhaps make the second single quote at the end optional `('[^']*''?|[^\s|,]+)` See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/QkkGLv/1)

Comment: @LeonardoChirivì Does that solve your problem?

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes seems to do fine. Thank you very much

Comment: @LeonardoChirivì You are welcome. I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to solve to problem for your current data is to add an optional single quote:

```
('[^']*''?|[^\s|,]+)
        ^^
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VE2Wqo/1/)

If you want to match zero or more single quotes, you might use `'*` instead.